# Rails 4 has_and_belongs_to_many with multi-tenancy (apartment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, multi-tenant

I my application I use apartment to have multi-tenancy and postgresql, so each tenant is in a different schema.
I have a User model in public (schema) and a model Action in each tenant (schema).
I want to have a relation has_and_belongs_to_many between those two models.
It works fine if I disable multi-tenancy.

I have read on the apartment's site that habtm doesn't work because there is no model to exclude, but it's not my case. I don't want to exclude it. The relation table is **in** the tenant schema, with the model Action. Only User is declare to be excluded (so User is in public).

I have an error message saying PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR: schma « actions_public » doesn't exist.

How can I do ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First of all: Did you follow all the steps to setup `apartment` in `apartment.rb`? Like defining `excluded_models` and `persistent_schemas`? You are using Postgresql, did you set `config.use_schemas = true`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, in initializers/apartments.rb, I put `config.excluded_models = %w{User}` to exclude my User model and 'config.use_schemas = true', but I don't use config.persistent_schemas.

Comment: Would love to help - but I am still leaning about multi-tenancy :) Hope it works out for you

Comment: Thank you :-) But for now, it's still doesn't work... Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my on question.

Because of the design of Apartment, it's not possible to use a habtm relation when a model is excluded on the other one is not.
The solution is to use a `has_many :through` relation.
Thanks.

Comment: Not to ask a question within a comment, but it appears you are using devise and I have exactly the same situation.  Are you able to convert devise to has_many :through?

Comment: I don't use Devise in this application (I use it in other application...) Sorry, I can't help you.